# How to make vtiger CRM RTL (Right to left) on changes of language like arabic etc?

Tags: right-to-left, vtiger, vtigercrm

i am new to vtiger CRM. I want to make crm RTL on the basis of the language selection using code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line into layouts/v7/modules/Vtiger/Header.tpl before closing head tag.

```
{if $LANGUAGE == 'fa_ir'  || $LANGUAGE == 'he_il'  || $LANGUAGE == 'fa_af'  || $LANGUAGE == 'ar_ae'}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hamidrabiei/36b4eef244db2ac3cce42083caccf032/raw/920e3e1c4fe8dc094254798c498f7fc8fc2e94e1/rtl.css?theme={$CURRENT_USER_MODEL->get('theme')}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
{/if}
```

Comment: Hello @hamid, I added this code into my header.tpl but didn't work.

Comment: check css file exists on page